# QGIS Put a label only on selected polygons

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule

I'd like to labelling only some polygons of a layer which are inside another polygon from another layer. Have you an idea how to do this? May be with a label rule?

Answer (score 6):

In the `Label with` option, try an expression like below:

```
CASE WHEN aggregate(layer:='another_polygon', aggregate:='count', 
                    expression:="id", filter:=within(geometry(@parent), $geometry))>0
THEN "your_label" 
ELSE NULL 
END
```

- `another_polygon` is the name of your *another polygon layer*
- `"id"` can be any attribute field in *your polygon layer*
- `"your_label"` is the attribute field you want to show

[image]

In this example **within()** function ensures the polygons are totally within the other polygon layer. If partial overlaps should be allowed, use **intersects()** instead.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with QGIS 3.16 Hannover, you can use the new `overlay_*` functions.

so it would be enough to write:

```
 if(overlay_within( 'another_polygon')=True,  "nome" , NULL)
```

[image]

https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/it/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_within#geometry-functions